# How to use Sapply in multiple dataframms

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, sapply

I have three dataframes: `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, I want to use `sapply` to browse the max of each dataframe, instead of using

```
sapply(AAA, max)
sapply(BBB, max)
sapply(CCC, max)
```

I tried to use a loop to solve this function, I tried the following lines, but didn't work

```
dfs = list(AAA, BBB, CCC)

for(df in dfs){
  print(deparse(substitute(df)))
  print(sapply(df, max))
  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
}
```

I intended to use
`print(deparse(substitute(df)))` to print out  `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`. However, all I got is `df`.

I wonder how to fix this problem.

Or is there any other way to apply `sapply` to multiple dataframes at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may loop over the `list` of data.frames and then use `sapply` on the dataset

```
lapply(dfs, \(dat) sapply(dat, max))
```

---

Or another option is `colMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
lapply(dfs, \(dat) colMaxs(as.matrix(dat)))
```

---

If we want to print the object names, it should be a named list and then loop over either the sequence of list or the names of the list and `print` the names

```
dfs <- list(AAA = AAA, BBB = BBB, CCC = CCC)
for(nm in names(dfs)) {
   print(nm)
   print(sapply(dfs[[nm]], max))
}
```